# Java Design Pattern - Business Delegate

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've got some questions regarding Java design patterns. I want to know what the lookup service and the business service in the business delegate pattern are exactly used for. I appreciate as much details and information as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *business delegate pattern* tries to decouple the clients from the business services. To achieve this you need:

- **business delegate** that is the object used by clients to request for services;
- **lookup service** is a bridge used by **business delegate** to search for services, it encapsulates the search algorithm according to the request made by the delegate;
- **business service** is the actual service that is offered to clients, usually an EJB or similar J2EE concepts.

By the way this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/businessdelegate-137562.html) explains everything quite clearly..

Comment: Thank you. I already found the page, but you explained it very good, I think I understand a little bit more now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The **Business Delegate** acts as a client-side business abstraction; it provides an abstraction for, and thus hides, the implementation of the business services.

Using a *Business Delegate* reduces the coupling between presentation-tier *clients* and the system's *Business services*

A *Business Delegate* uses a component called the *Lookup Service*. The Lookup Service is responsible for hiding the underlying implementation details of the *Business service* lookup code.

The *Business service* is a business-tier component, such as an enterprise bean or a JMS component, that provides the required service to the client. It is used to invoke the business methods on behalf of the client.

Structure:

[image]

You can find more details about this pattern in [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/businessdelegate-137562.html) website.